# Material ui Autocomplete: Get updated options list while user is typing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I'm using material ui autocomplete, and i want to get the new filtered list shown in the dropdown while user is typing .

like in first image we have the full list :

[image]

end here we have the updated list (3 elements) after user typed "amer" ;

[image]

is there a way to get the elements of the new list ?

autocomplete code :

```
<Autocomplete
        freeSolo
        id="free-solo-2-demo"
        disableClearable
        options={top100Films.map((option) => option.title)}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Search input"
            InputProps={{
              ...params.InputProps,
              type: 'search',
            }}
          />
        )}
/>
```

Comment: what do you mean by saying **get the elements of the new list** ?

Comment: i mean the new options list (filtered list after user typed something)